# IndexOutOfBoundsException when using "in" function in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geotools, sld

I have trouble with the `in` filter function in SLD submitted to GeoServer. The root cause seems to be within the geotools. Currently we're using `GeoServer Version 2.15.2` and `GeoTools Version 21.2`. The fact is that with less complex filters the `in` function seems to work but in this case it does not. We found also an workaround by using `or` in combination with `PropertyIsEqualTo` but then the payload is much bigger. I've tried also to split the `in` function into smaller parts so it matches `in9` or `in10` but then i got similar `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:Or>
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:Function name="geometryType">
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Literal>Point</ogc:Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:Function name="geometryType">
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Literal>MultiPoint</ogc:Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Or>
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:Function name="in">
                <ogc:Function name="property">
                  <ogc:Literal>feature_type_id</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:Literal>7516</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7517</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7518</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7519</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7520</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7521</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7522</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7523</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7524</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7525</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7526</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7527</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7528</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7529</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7530</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7531</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7532</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7533</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7534</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7535</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>7536</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:And>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
```

The generated SLD may be found here https://gofile.io/d/RWLOUS

Here is a part of the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:873)
    at org.geotools.filter.FunctionExpressionImpl.accept(FunctionExpressionImpl.java:143)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visitBinaryComparisonOperator(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:423)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:377)
    at org.geotools.filter.IsEqualsToImpl.accept(IsEqualsToImpl.java:154)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visitLogicOperator(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:670)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:599)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.accept(AndImpl.java:45)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visitLogicOperator(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:627)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:604)
    at org.geotools.filter.NotImpl.accept(NotImpl.java:51)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visitLogicOperator(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:670)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:599)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.accept(AndImpl.java:45)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visitLogicOperator(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:627)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:604)
    at org.geotools.filter.NotImpl.accept(NotImpl.java:51)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visitLogicOperator(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:649)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:609)
    at org.geotools.filter.OrImpl.accept(OrImpl.java:41)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visitLogicOperator(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:670)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.visit(PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor.java:599)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.accept(AndImpl.java:45)
```

I've also tried to create a unit test in `PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitorTest` in geotools which would simulate a part of the xml, but it does not throw any exception

```java
final Not not =
  ff.not(
    ff.and(
      ff.or(
        ff.equal(
          ff.function("geometryType", ff.property("geom")),
            ff.literal("Point"),
            true,
            MultiValuedFilter.MatchAction.ANY
        ),
        ff.equal(
          ff.function("geometryType", ff.property("geom")),
          ff.literal("MultiPoint"),
          true,
          MultiValuedFilter.MatchAction.ANY
        )
      ),
      ff.equal(
        ff.function(
          "in", 
          ff.function("property", ff.literal("feature_type_id")),
          ff.literal(7516),
          ff.literal(7517),
          ff.literal(7518),
          ff.literal(7519),
          ff.literal(7520),
          ff.literal(7521),
          ff.literal(7522),
          ff.literal(7523),
          ff.literal(7524),
          ff.literal(7525),
          ff.literal(7526),
          ff.literal(7527),
          ff.literal(7528),
          ff.literal(7529),
          ff.literal(7530),
          ff.literal(7531),
          ff.literal(7532),
          ff.literal(7533),
          ff.literal(7534),
          ff.literal(7535),
          ff.literal(7536)
        ),
        ff.literal(true),
        true,
        MultiValuedFilter.MatchAction.ANY
      )
    )
  );
  final And andFilter = ff.and(Collections.singletonList(not));
  final PostPreProcessFilterSplittingVisitor postprocessFilter =
                newVisitor(new FilterCapabilities());
        
  andFilter.accept(postprocessFilter, null);
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recent fix in GeoTools which fixes this issue https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6746